# Navigation Provider for representing hierarchy in between pages based on managed metadata

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, managed-navigation

I would like to know if there is any built-in navigation provider for SharePoint 2013 that would provide me the possibility to create hierarchy in between pages in a way that shows the whole tree on the left panel with full path, and those pages hierarchy would be based on managed metadata.